# Anonymous user edited data as draft/revision in drupal 6

Tags: 6, nodes

I have a problem(may be only for me).  My requirement is anonymous user or registered user if they like to make a modification in a node they should be permitted but the modifications made by them should be saved as draft until the admin approves them.

Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the [Workflow](http://drupal.org/project/workflow) module.  You probably also need the [Revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning), [Module Grants](http://drupal.org/project/module_grants) and [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) modules.